# Angular which router outlet is used

Tags: angular

I’m new to Angular and I get that component templates are loaded below the router-outlet. However, I get really confused when the are multiple nested child routes. I really struggle at figuring out quickly which router outlet will be used when there are multiple nested child routes. What’s the ´trick’ to know which router outlet will be used? What should I understand that I don’t? Maybe there is a way of organizing things so that is it less confusing to know where a particular component will be loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Each `router-outlet` should relate back to the parent modules routing module, for example

If I had a `app.routing.module.ts` this is imported then by `app.module.ts` which means any `router-outlets` in any of the components within the `app.module.ts` will relate to the `app.routing.module.ts`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <-- app.routing.module.ts
```

now in the case of nested `router-outlet`

say within my `app.module.ts` I have a `user.module.ts`, now for this module (`user.module.ts`) to have independant routing it will need to import a routing module like so `user.routing.module.ts` and then the same applies if I put a `router-outlet` within any component within the `user.module.ts` it will use the `user.routing.module.ts` and not the `app.routing.module.ts`

```html
app.component.html
   <router-outlet></router-outlet> <-- app.routing.module.ts
       user.component.html
          <router-outlet></router-outlet> <-- user.routing.module.ts
```

So easiest way to think about it is, whatever module your router-outlet is in, is what your `router-outlet` relates to.

As for organisation.. you could put comments next to your `router-outlet` to make it easier for yourself?

```
<!-- app.router.module.ts -->
<router-oulet></router-outlet>
```